# ListView con SQL en Android

Tags: android, sql

tengo una base de datos sql donde se guardan los productos el problema es que quiero que al mostrar los datos en el list view quiero que tenga botones, checkbox,txtview,plaintext, en cada registro que se guarde y se muestre en el listview con esos botonos.

Mi codigo:

```
private ListView lst1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nueva_orden);

    lst1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lst1);


    //-----------------------------
    //Cargando Registros de la Base de Datos
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper( this, "administracion", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();

    ArrayList<String> ranking = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor fila = BaseDeDatos.rawQuery("select codigo, producto, precio from articulos", null);
    if(fila.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            //diseño de los registros
            ranking.add(fila.getString(0) + fila.getString(1) + " " + fila.getString(2));
        }while(fila.moveToNext());
    }
    BaseDeDatos.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ranking);
    lst1.setAdapter(adapter);
    //-----------------------------------------------

}
```

por los momentos solo puedo mostrar los registros guardados en sql alguien exolique como hacerlo.

---

El problema Es que aun no encuentro lo que busco.
ejemplo: quiero que al mostrar los registros de mis productos quiero que cada registro muestre un chekbox asi al seleccionar los chekbox hacer una suma depende de los registros seleccionados pero no encuentro como adaptar un ckekbox en el listview cuando se muestran los registros de la base de datos.

Comment: Estas muy lejos del objetivo, para empezar yo cogería los valores de la BBDD y los almacenaría en un objeto no en una string si son múltiples valores. Respecto a los botones en el listView te recomiendo que utilices un custom adapter con el adapter genérico no vas a poder hacerlo.

Comment: Me parece que es demasiado amplia esta pregunta, revisa [ask], te sugiero construyas tu BD , te sugiero revises este tutorial: http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-sqlite-bases-de-datos/

Comment: TE RECOMIENDO BASEADAPTER AQUI TE DEJO UN LINK EN GITHUB DE UN EJEMPLO COMPLETO https://github.com/mayojava/ListViewWithBaseAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

veo por su código que estas empezando en el mundo de Android o bien sólo estas haciendo un ejemplo para aprendizaje. En todo caso le recomiendo que siempre busques en el sitio oficial de Android el comportamiento de los componentes. Adjunto [enlace](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView) (en inglés lo siento pero no esta en español pero te servirá de referencia) .

Sobre su problema, veo en su código que se basó en un ejemplo para el ListView similar a [este](https://elbauldelprogramador.com/programacion-android-interfaz-grafica_28/) donde utilizas String y un adapter simple conformado por un `ArrayList<String>`

`new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ranking);`

Lo anterior funciona bien para listas donde necesites solo mostrar 1 sólo texto simple. Para su pregunta recomiendo el siguiente [enlace](http://www.proyectosimio.com/es/programacion-android-listview-adapter-personalizado-i/)  donde puedes aprender a hacer un custom adapter con un objeto "animal" en su caso será un objeto articulo.

Algo similar a esto:

`ArticuloAdapter adapter;`

`// Inicializamos el adapter.`

`adapter = new ArticuloAdapter(this, arrayListArticulos);`

`// Asignamos el Adapter al ListView, en este punto hacemos que el ListView muestre los datos que queremos.`

`lst1.setAdapter(adapter);`

Nota: asumo que sabes llenar el arrayList con objetos, es cambiar simplemente que no sea de tipo String sino de tipo articulo y agregar articulos a la lista.

Espero que sea de ayuda, recuerda investigar un poco sobre los componentes que usas y suerte con la aplicación.